# Bootstrap's tooltips require Popper.js - Karma Jasmine TypeError

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Attempting to run a unit test on an Angular 8 component that uses bootstrap's(v4) popovers. The unit test failed after including the appropriate file stating:

> TypeError: Bootstrap's tooltips require Popper.js
>   (https://popper.js.org/)

I've tried a few different configurations in my karma.conf file but nothing has seemed to work. Right now Karma runs but doesn't hit any of the tests after adding popper to the files array unless I manually hit the debug button which is unusual and then it still displays the same error above. Here's what my configuration looks like right now. Any insight greatly appreciated.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular', 'jquery-3.3.1'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-jquery')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    files: [
      '../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js',
      '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: Is ng-bootstrap a possibility? I don't believe they require Popper.js. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

Comment: I'm just using bootstrap in this case, not ngbootstrap. If you mean to just replace it using that package's version, perhaps, but that would require an overhaul of the component using it. @xsoftie